# Handling MYSQL Loop for from week and to week

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL Query like this and the resultset is getting fetched.

```
    select mb.book_code, mb.from_date, mb.to_date, 
          week(mb.from_date) from_wk, week(mb.to_date) to_wk
     from master_book mb;



    Table Name: master_book

    book_code   from_date   to_date     from_wk     to_wk
    ====================================================== 
    143         2014-01-01  2014-01-31  1           5
```

What I would like to get with my query is like this.

## Expected Output

```
book_code   from_date   to_date         wk_1        wk_2    wk_3    wk_4    wk_5    
====================================================== 
143         2014-01-01  2014-01-31      -           -       -       -       -
```

I know I have to do some loop in my mysql query. But no idea. Even I have searched the net.

Please guide me if I'm wrong.

Thanks,
Kimz

Comment: Can you post the structure of the tables?

Comment: This may be useful: [Common MySQL Queries](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78). see 'Pivot tables (crosstabs)'